# Handling quoted string passed to Blade::directive() in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel

Given the custom blade directive:

```
Blade::directive('svg', function ($expression) {
    return "<?php echo public_path(\"img/{$expression}.svg\"); ?>";
});
```

Called by:

```
@svg('jason');
```

Yields an error due to the quotes appearing in the resulting PHP:

```
<?php echo public_path("img/'jason'.svg"); ?>
```

I feel like the wrapping quotes should have been removed for me… Do I need to remove them myself? Is there a better way?

Comment: Yes, they need to be removed manually. Since blade templating directives are designed for less syntax, it does not need quotes* (are some exceptions with `if` statements). You could always alternatively remove the first and last character of `$expression` before using it.

Comment: You could instead `<?php echo myFunc$expression ?>` which will result in `<?php echo myFunc('jason'); ?>` I believe.

Comment: @Derek, seems so ugly. Hoped there was a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I always use single quotes inside of double quotes. It works.

```
Blade::directive('svg', function ($expression) {
    return "<?php echo public_path('img/'.{$expression}.'.svg'); ?>";
});
```

Comment: This was not the question

Answer (score 0):

Since Laravel double encode your jason string (which i don't know why !), the easy way i figure out to solve this issue by passing jason string to @svg directive without quotes.

```
@svg(jason);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another working solution is to `trim` your string before passing it to `public_path()` function :

```
Blade::directive('svg', function ($expression) {
    $expression = trim($expression, "\'\"");    
    return "<?php echo public_path(\"img/{$expression}.svg\"); ?>";
});

@svg('jason'); // works fine
@svg("jason"); // works fine
```